# Voyager's distance from Earth

Tags: communication, telemetry

If it took Voyager’s radio signal 4 hours to cross the solar system and reach Earth, roughly how far away in AU was Voyager from Earth when it sent that signal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like a homework question, and I don't think it belongs here.

Comment: @Phiteros: That's a reasonable downvote reason, but "homework" is a close reason on no site that I am aware of, not even SO.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Normally that wouldn't concern me, but I just feel like this question is rather low quality and does not really contribute anything.

Comment: @Phiteros Yes, that's what downvotes are for! You *close* questions that *cannot be usefully answered*; you *downvote* questions that *aren't worth answering*. I considered downvoting until I checked Bing for `4 light hours in au` and found nothing useful.

Comment: Plug the same text into Google and the first result is a calculator that can do this conversion...

Comment: @NathanTuggy Homework questions are routinely closed on [cs.se].

Answer (score 4):

[About 29 au away.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=speed%20of%20light%20*%204%20hours)  Speed * time = distance (since speed has units of distance/time). For this problem, the units are as follows:
$$C \text{ meters}/\text{second} * 4 \text{ hours} * (60*60) \text{ seconds}/\text{hour} \approx 4*10^{12} \text{ meters} \approx 29 \text{ au}$$
I didn't know the conversion off the top of my head so I used trusty Wolfram Alpha.